# How to send form data from WordPress (Meta Box) to an OData service?

Tags: php, forms

I have created a form within a Meta Box on the 'Add New Page' screen.

I want the data from this form to be sent to an OData service on a central server.

I can see that OData is supported on PHP (http://odataphp.codeplex.com/) but it requires the **OData for PHP SDK** to be installed on the server. Because the server could be Windows/UNIX/LINUX/other I don't know if I can create a generic installation file to make it transparent for the user to install my plugin.

What would be the best method of doing this?

Comment: How can your plugin work on WordPress.com when WordPress.com does not support 3rd party plugins? Also OData is a large and complex service: http://www.odata.org/developers/protocols/operations Which specific operations are you trying to support? Please give us your use-case so we can better understand what you are asking

Comment: This is my 1st plugin, I didn't realise that wordpress.com doesn't support 3rd party plugins. Thanks for the info! I want users to complete a form (within a meta box on the 'Add new post' page) which will give details of cars. When they add the post, the form data will be displayed in their post and also submitted (via OData) to an OData service on a public server. The server will then process the data and display it on a website.

Comment: If you have general questions about writing a plugin, ask them. If you have specific questions about making use of ODdata, than you've asked your question on the wrong site. Please check the FAQ.

Comment: @hakre This question is valid. I am asking how I can embed the OData SDK within my WordPress plugin. I do know how I want to use OData, I only explained the intended usage of it in my above comment because @MikeSchinkel asked for the use case

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. You can embed the OData SDK with wordpress just like with anything PHP. Install, Configure, done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So basically what you're asking is how to create a php-based installer for the OData SDK, right? Or how to somehow package it with your plugin?

First I thought you could just include the whole framework in your plugin folder, and include it directly from there. But it turns out (from reading the install docs) that installation of the SDK requires some actual changes to the php ini outside of just adding the include path, and the SDK itself has several dependencies (php-xml, php-xsml, curl modules).

In short, I don't think you can do this effectively with a php-based installer. And I don't know of any WordPress-specific bundling techniques that help.

My best advice is: find another way to do the remote logging that doesn't rely on OData. For example, build a simple REST service on your centralized server that can be hit using wp_http.

If you NEED to use OData for some reason, simply make it a prerequisite for your plugin. Find a way to test for its existence, and spit out a warning that says "you need the OData SDK" if it isn't installed.

If none of that helps, try contacting folks who work on the OData SDK (http://odataphp.codeplex.com/team/view). Distributing this software isn't really an issue that's specific to WordPress... they may have better general advice for making a portable php-based installer.

Comment: Thank you for the good answer. I don't want to have to rely on people having the OData SDK already installed (because my intended audience won't be that technical) so I will look at using REST with wp_http. I will also ask on http://odataphp.codeplex.com/team/view. Thanks.